# getopt make two options mandatory

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, getopt

I am using python getopt to parse the arguments that user gives.

```
try:
    options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hl:d:r:',
                                    ['h','help','lo=','dat=','rel='])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(err)
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in options:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        usage()
        sys.exit()
    elif opt == "--lo":

    elif opt == "--dat":

    elif opt == '--rel':
```

how can we pair two options together i.e if the user gives --dat option he should definitely provide --rel option or else we exit.

can we do that using getopt?

Thanks

Comment: Another way is to just have both `dat` and `rel` arguments in one flag. (i.e seperated by a comma or something). Or check manually that they both exist. I'm not aware of any options in `getopt` that allows for such.

Comment: If you're interested in trying an alternative to getopt, `argparse` would let you do this.